# dpkg warning caused by missing steam-libs-i386:i386

Tags: 20.04, package-management, software-installation, dpkg, steam

Few months ago I accidentally removed two packages: `steam-libs-i386:i386` and `steam-libs-amd64`. Sometimes, when I need to install a new package, I see this warnings after an `apt install`:

```
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'steam-libs-i386:i386' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'steam-libs-amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
```

So far, I have always been able to correctly install the packages, but I would like to remove them before they become an issue of some kind, assuming they will.

After running:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall steam-libs-i386:i386
sudo apt-get install --reinstall steam-libs-amd64
```

The returned message is

```
Reinstallation of steam-libs-amd64 is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.
```

Same goes for `steam-libs-i386:i386`.

Do I need them? How can I reinstall them? Or, if not necessary, how to get rid of the warning?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running?  Those libs are not in the standard repos for 20.04, where did you get them?  What needs them?  Seems like you didn't remove them via the package manger, but just deleted some files -- apt remove --purge them

Comment: The version is in the tags, 20.04. If they are not in the standard repos, they probably come from an installation of Steam that I removed shortly after. I do not remember, that is why I have asked. by the way, thanks for the suggestion, the `--purge` option seems to have solved the problem. Please re-write the comment as an answer so that I can accept it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you didn't remove them via the package manger, but just deleted some files. To fix, purge the packages:

```
sudo  apt remove --purge steam-libs-amd64 steam-libs-i386:i386
```